# Wordpress Custom Theme - Applying Updates

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I haven't been able to look this information up online. Perhaps I am not searching correctly.

I'm looking for information on the best practices. I have a custom built Wordpress theme that I want to implement on several similar websites. On each of the websites, I then intend to implement a child theme so that parts of each site can be customized, while still utilizing the parent theme.

I don't want my parent theme to be downloadable for other users, just myself.

I'm sure that "copying and pasting" the main theme from one of the sites to the others isn't best practice, because if an update needed to be made, I'd have to do it across all the sites. Ideally, I'd like to able to apply an update, and then within the dashboard of each of the sites, just "update" the theme.

What would be the best practice for this? Or am I misinformed about how this all works? Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can perhaps try multisite - https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network.

Comment: I believe for multisite all the websites need to be on the same domain. In my scenario, all the websites are on different domain names.

Comment: I think that might be more complex than what I'm looking for. Basically, I want the main "parent" theme to act like any other theme, and on each of the individual sites, when I make an update, you get the update notification to update the theme - just like if Wordpress made an update to Twenty Seventeen. In my case, however, I don't want the theme to be in a public space that can be downloaded by anyone else.